# Convert string to integer/ date to calculate the age difference in Mongosh

Tags: mongodb

I have a dataset for the laureates of Nobel prize since its inception. The birth_date is a string that comes as '1949-03-28'. The year of the award comes as an integer eg. 2000.
I'd like to know the age of each individual at the time of laureation.

I go as far as substringing the birth_date to extract the year. But I don't know how to convert it to int and subsequently calculate the subtraction between year(birth_date) and the year(laureation).

I've looked on other posts, but nothing that really encompasses everything I need to do

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of gymnastics, you can convert both to a `Date` and diff them. It could look like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      ageWhenAwarded: {
        $dateDiff: {
          startDate: {
            $toDate: '$birth_date'
          },
          endDate: {
            $toDate: {
              $concat: [
                { $toString: '$award_year' },
                '-01-01'
              ],
            }
          },
          unit: 'year'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

This produces a document like so:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("63b7555beb9dcf4f317b43ae"),
  award_year: 2000,
  birth_date: '1949-03-28',
  ageWhenAwarded: 51
}
```

The ages will be approximate, since [Durations are measured by counting the number of times a unit boundary is passed](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/), but you only have `award_year` anyway, so I suspect that's okay (the other option would be to convert the dates to ints, subtract them, and divide by the number of milliseconds in a year).

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. Smtng needs to be tweaked, there was a error msg: "MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Error parsing date string 'NA'; 0: passing a time zone identifier as part of the string is not allowed 'N'" Would you know what's wrong?

Comment: It sounds like some of your `birth_date` or `award_year` fields have a value of `NA`?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Tks. The birth_date has some NA's. Would you know how I can overcome that?

Comment: Overcome how? Depends what you want to do with those records.

Comment: I've deleted the NA's and it worked. It wasn't what I wanted, but it's just a assignment, so I can get away with doing so. Thanks a lot for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Nice, if this answer solved your problem, you can mark it accepted and upvote to its left.

Comment: Cheers, I've accepted, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote.